# User does not create tables using assigned default schema in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm having an issue with SQL Server 2014 after returning to it from having a year off.

I've created the schema "dba" and assigned it to users default schema's on the database that are attached to Logins on the server e.g. Login1

So Login1 user has a default schema of dba

The problem I'm having is that when I create a table using:

```
Create table Test (Test int)
```

It creates the table as **dbo.Test**

However as I'm logged in as say Login1, I'm expecting it to create it as **dba.Test**

If I run this code:

```
Execute as user = 'Login1'
Create Table Test (Test int)
```

Then I am given the desired result of dba.Test

I'm not sure what further information can help you help me with this but if you let me know I'll provide it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is very unusual. Maybe remove the DDL permissions for the dbo schema for Login1?

Comment: Can you run this statement in both contexts? SELECT CURRENT_USER

Comment: Try to run SELECT SCHEMA_NAME() in both contexts to see the current active default schema.

Comment: Thanks guys, I ran Select Current_User and Select Schema_name and both returned dbo. I certainly wasn't expecting that. dbo belongs to user sa. Login1 is what I login as, although that was previously assigned to user dbo but I changed it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your help with this. After trying `Select Current_User` and realising that my login was still using dbo instead of Login1 that something was definitely not right.

I read the following and realised the problem was that Login1 was assigned sysadmin role and this mapped to dbo. Any level below this maps your user to itself so I simply changed their role to serveradmin and hey presto it started working:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905208(v=sql.80).aspx